# Like button code with DotNetNuke

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke

I administer a web site that uses DotNetNuke, I can add a html module, but I am trying to use the like button from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ it generates the code for me, which is all good, but when I add this code to my site it has no effect, would you be able to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you
[facebook button for dotnetnuke blog](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2741/Adding-a-Facebook-Like-Button-to-Your-DotNetNuke-Blog.aspx)